# Is there any way to prevent document and window server side rendering in nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Is there any enable server side rendering to document and window in nuxt.js app?

using `process.browser` working fine

```js
if (process.browser) {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
}
```

But I have to use everywhere window or document is used. I'm looking for way to setting it globally.

Comment: you are doing something wrong if u need it everywhere. window and document dont exist on server and shouldnt be used everywhere for ssr apps

Comment: Use `<no-ssr>` element to avoid `process.browser` everywhere...